# i want to blur an image with js but its not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is the small part code which i have write but its not working and img is the variable which i have store img ID in it

let filtercn=document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]');

```
<div >
                        <span>Blur</span>
                        <input id="blur" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" onchange="applyFilter()" data-filter="blur" data-scale="px"><br>
                    </div>
    function applyFilter(){
        let fl='';
        filtercn.forEach(function(s){
        fl+=s.getAttribute('data-filter')+'('+s.value+s.getAttribute('data-scale') +')';       
        });
        img.style.filter=fl;
    };
```

Comment: Have you checked devtools?

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/imageblur.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Not exacly what you asked, but I'd do it via CSS:

```
filter: blur(10px);
```

EDIT
You can also do something like this (jQuery or JS are either ok of course):

```
onchange="$(this).css('filter','blur(10px)');"
```

Answer (score 0):

Editing on Riccardo LV's Answer without putting it in a different css file just do the following,

```
function applyFilter(img){
    img.css.filter = "blur(10px)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not wrong;

This is what you have used, just a bit cleaner and it does work :)

```js
let filtercn = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]');
let img = document.querySelectorAll('img')[0];

function applyFilter() {
  let fl = '';
  filtercn.forEach(function(s) {
    fl += s.getAttribute('data-filter') + '(' + s.value + s.getAttribute('data-scale') + ')';
  });
  img.style.filter = fl;
};
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Blur</span>
  <input id="blur" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" onchange="applyFilter()" data-filter="blur" data-scale="px">
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gghf3M5ETbqkndUt57cgaUALuAW2cJ_o-O7r4H7=k-s64">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no image in your code. so added an image and made the function more simple.

```js
function applyFilter() {
    let image = document.getElementById("image");
    let blurVal = document.getElementById("blur").value;
    image.style.filter = "blur("+blurVal+"px)"
}
```

```css
#image {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div >
    <span>Blur</span>
    <img id="image"  src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/11/16/14/43/cat-1045782_960_720.jpg" alt="">
    <input id="blur" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" onchange="applyFilter()"><br>
</div>
```